# MSVC emplace_hint is too slow

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++

I just tried the following code I adapted from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace_hint in a bunch of compilers. Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <functional>
#include <map>

const int nof_operations = 1000000;

int map_emplace() {
    std::map<int, char> map;
    for (int i = 0; i < nof_operations; ++i) {
        map.emplace(i, 'a');
    }
    return map.size();
}

int map_emplace_hint() {
    std::map<int, char> map;
    auto it = map.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < nof_operations; ++i) {
        map.emplace_hint(it, i, 'b');
        it = map.end();
    }
    return map.size();
}

int map_emplace_hint_wrong() {
    std::map<int, char> map;
    auto it = map.begin();
    for (int i = nof_operations; i > 0; --i) {
        map.emplace_hint(it, i, 'c');
        it = map.end();
    }
    return map.size();
}

int map_emplace_hint_corrected() {
    std::map<int, char> map;
    auto it = map.begin();
    for (int i = nof_operations; i > 0; --i) {
        map.emplace_hint(it, i, 'd');
        it = map.begin();
    }
    return map.size();
}

int map_emplace_hint_closest() {
    std::map<int, char> map;
    auto it = map.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < nof_operations; ++i) {
        it = map.emplace_hint(it, i, 'e');
    }
    return map.size();
}

void timeit(std::function<int()> map_test, std::string what = "") {
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    int mapsize = map_test();
    auto stop = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> time = stop - start;
    if (what.size() > 0 && mapsize > 0) {
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << std::setw(5)
            << time.count() << "  ms for " << what << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    timeit(map_emplace); // stack warmup
    timeit(map_emplace, "plain emplace");
    timeit(map_emplace_hint, "emplace with correct hint");
    timeit(map_emplace_hint_wrong, "emplace with wrong hint");
    timeit(map_emplace_hint_corrected, "corrected emplace");
    timeit(map_emplace_hint_closest, "emplace using returned iterator");
}
```

I found that MSVC's emplace_hint is consistently slower than g++ on WSL or on Ubuntu.

My benchmarks:

`g++ Main.cpp -Ofast && ./a.out` on WSL or Ubuntu

```
179.01  ms for plain emplace
51.59  ms for emplace with correct hint
180.08  ms for emplace with wrong hint
45.99  ms for corrected emplace
47.67  ms for emplace using returned iterator
```

Visual Studio MSVC with all optimizations

```
193.36  ms for plain emplace
127.33  ms for emplace with correct hint
206.15  ms for emplace with wrong hint
127.07  ms for corrected emplace
192.91  ms for emplace using returned iterator
```

Mingw `g++ Main.cpp -Ofast && a`

```
155.82  ms for plain emplace
104.26  ms for emplace with correct hint
156.06  ms for emplace with wrong hint
99.40  ms for corrected emplace
103.03  ms for emplace using returned iterator
```

Plain emplace's performance is very similar, but for some reason emplace_hint on MSVC gives almost no performance improvement. What could explain such thing?

Comment: Why do you say no improvement? To me it seems like a 35% improvement (193->127).

Comment: Ok, but still much less than the other one ^^